# Have to fetch data from database and enter into textbox

Tags: c#

I have to fetch data from database and enter into textbox in my form.My Form has textboxes and gridview(for some textboxes alone).I have to fetch data from database based on selected grid view cell=PROJECTNAME and enter into other textboxes matching that criteria.
I have done my coding part  for single textbox and its showing "{"ORA-00904: \"PRIME\": invalid identifier"}"

Kindly help me with the following

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TEST"].ToString());
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
string prime = gdDisplay.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCRIPTION FROM CMPPOJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = prime";
string str= cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
txtDescription.Text = str;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

There is no need to keep calling `.ToString()` as `getValue` is already a string. and also need to take care that the string values has to be quoted in the `''` single quotes.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCRIPTION FROM CMPPOJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = 'prime'";
var str= cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

We can just put a check to see if the value is null

```
if (str!= null) {
    txtDescription.Text = str.ToString();
}
```

and apart from that you could use this as well

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCRIPTION FROM CMPPOJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = 'prime'";
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    txtDescription.Text = reader["DESCRIPTION"].ToString().Trim();
}
```

Comment: I have not getting any error and also values too in textbox

Comment: Than what is your issue? What's your question

Answer (score 1):

change

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCRIPTION FROM CMPPOJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = prime";
```

to

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCRIPTION FROM CMPPOJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = 'prime'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You may get result by changing the query to

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCRIPTION FROM CMPPOJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = 'prime'";
```

i.e by adding quotes to the passing identifier. But it is **not safe** to do so and might expose to sql injection problems. For example if someone tries to search with a keyword like --> Where ProjectName = **'Anil's Project'**, note there comes three quotes causing confusion to the query

A safe way and a good practice from the beginning itself is using parameters. Its simple. Do like

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCRIPTION FROM CMPPOJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = @ProjectName";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", "prime"); // don't use  additional quotes inside like "'prime'"

string str= cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```